# How to create a Chord Sample in Logic Pro X

Tags: logic-pro, guitar

I start by saying that I'm totally new to Logic Pro.

**I need to sample some guitar chords**

Just that, without strumming or anything, just play the Chord once. Is there a way I can do it using Logic without having to record it from my guitar?

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: As in, using preexisting samples?

Comment: I was not able to find them online

Comment: Believe me, there are a lot. Are you just looking for some individual chord samples, or for a full guitar sample instrument?

Comment: if possible a full one

Comment: Look into something like Spicy Guitar (modeled acoustic, free), AAS's Strum GS (acoustic and electric, commercial, physical modeling) or any of the many guitar sample libraries.